# Undefined symbols when linking PhoneGap static library in MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am working on providing PhoneGap functionality in a UIWebView in MonoTouch. I have tested the functionality in Objective C and the static library works correctly there. However, when I try and link the PhoneGap static library into my MonoTouch application I get a long list of undefined symbols.

I have included all the header files for the PhoneGap library and I have also ensured that 'Compile for thumb' is unchecked when compiling the PhoneGap library. So I am not sure what I am missing and the error messages don't mean much to me. I will quote them here (it is a LONG list!), but hopefully someone here can enlighten me to what the linker is trying to tell me!

Here is the long list...

```
Undefined symbols:
"_ABPersonSetImageData", referenced from:
  -[Contact setFromContactDict:asUpdate:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
"_kABPersonAddressStateKey", referenced from:
  _kABPersonAddressStateKey$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonAddressStateKey$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel", referenced from:
  _kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kABPersonEmailProperty", referenced from:
  _kABPersonEmailProperty$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonEmailProperty$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kABPersonNoteProperty", referenced from:
  _kABPersonNoteProperty$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonNoteProperty$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kABWorkLabel", referenced from:
  _kABWorkLabel$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABWorkLabel$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers", referenced from:
  _kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers$non_lazy_ptr)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-CLLocationManager in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
"_kABPersonInstantMessageServiceICQ", referenced from:
  _kABPersonInstantMessageServiceICQ$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonInstantMessageServiceICQ$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kABPersonInstantMessageServiceMSN", referenced from:
  _kABPersonInstantMessageServiceMSN$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonInstantMessageServiceMSN$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey", referenced from:
  _kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters", referenced from:
  _kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer", referenced from:
  _kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer$non_lazy_ptr)
"_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
  -[File getMimeTypeFromPath:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
"_ABPersonCreate", referenced from:
  -[Contact init] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
"_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
  -[File getMimeTypeFromPath:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
"_kABPersonPhoneProperty", referenced from:
  _kABPersonPhoneProperty$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonPhoneProperty$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey", referenced from:
  _kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kABOtherLabel", referenced from:
  _kABOtherLabel$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABOtherLabel$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kABPersonBirthdayProperty", referenced from:
  _kABPersonBirthdayProperty$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonBirthdayProperty$non_lazy_ptr)
"_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
  _MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification$non_lazy_ptr)
"_ABMultiValueRemoveValueAndLabelAtIndex", referenced from:
  -[Contact setMultiValueStrings:forProperty:inRecord:asUpdate:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
  -[Contact setMultiValueDictionary:forProperty:inRecord:asUpdate:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
"_ABRecordRemoveValue", referenced from:
  -[Contact removeProperty:inRecord:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
"_ABAddressBookCreate", referenced from:
  -[Contacts newContact:withDict:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
  -[Contacts displayContact:withDict:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
  -[Contacts search:withDict:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
  -[Contacts save:withDict:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
  -[Contacts remove:withDict:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
"_ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex", referenced from:
  -[Contact setMultiValueStrings:forProperty:inRecord:asUpdate:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
  -[Contact setMultiValueDictionary:forProperty:inRecord:asUpdate:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
  -[Contact extractMultiValue:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
  -[Contact extractAddresses] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
  -[Contact extractIms] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-AVAudioPlayer in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
"_kABHomeLabel", referenced from:
  _kABHomeLabel$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABHomeLabel$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kABPersonInstantMessageProperty", referenced from:
  _kABPersonInstantMessageProperty$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonInstantMessageProperty$non_lazy_ptr)
"_kABPersonAddressZIPKey", referenced from:
  _kABPersonAddressZIPKey$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonAddressZIPKey$non_lazy_ptr)
"_ABPersonRemoveImageData", referenced from:
  -[Contact setFromContactDict:asUpdate:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
  -[Contact setFromContactDict:asUpdate:] in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
"_kABPersonAddressProperty", referenced from:
  _kABPersonAddressProperty$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonAddressProperty$non_lazy_ptr)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-MPMoviePlayerController in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
"_kABPersonInstantMessageServiceYahoo", referenced from:
  _kABPersonInstantMessageServiceYahoo$non_lazy_ptr in libPhoneGap.a(libPhoneGapLib.a-armv6-master.o)
 (maybe you meant: _kABPersonInstantMessageServiceYahoo$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process exited with code 1
```

Hope this makes sense to someone here, because it is greek to me! ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem; I was missing several framework entries that were required by the PhoneGap library. Specifically, these framework entries needed to be added to the gcc_flags:

```
-framework corelocation 
-framework mediaplayer
-framework messageui
-framework mobilecoreservices
-framework quartzcore
-framework systemconfiguration
-framework audiotoolbox
-framework avfoundation
-framework addressbook
-framework foundation
-framework coregraphics
-framework addressbookui
```